# Problem on convergence of Series (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is problem $3.11$  of Rudin's real Analysis.

Suppose $a_n>0$ , $s_n := a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ and that $\sum a_n$ diverges. Prove that

$\sum \dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}:=\sum b_n$ diverges.

I came across a solution book but my solution is different so i would like to know if i'm correct. I assume by contradiction that the series converges. If so then i showed that $a_n \to 0$ is a necessary condition. Having this in mind i proceeded as follows.

I applied the ratio test : $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup |\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup 
 |\dfrac{a_{n+1}(1+a_{n})}{a_n(1+a_{n+1})}|>\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup  |\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n(1+a_{n+1})}|$ (since $a_n>0$)$ \ \  \geq \lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup  |\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| \cdot  \lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup |\dfrac{1}{1+a_{n+1}}|=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup  |\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ (since $a_{n+1} \to 0$) $ \  \geq 1 \ \ $ (since $\sum a_n$ is divergent).

Hence by the ratio test the series is convergent. Is this proof correct?
Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: The ratio test is not a necessary and sufficient condition. So your proof is not quite correct, since you don't know that $\limsup\vert a_{n+1}/a_n\vert>1$.

Comment: @Etienne  so what is left is  to consider the case $\limsup\vert a_{n+1}/a_n\vert=1$ right? Wich still satisfies the ratio test since one of the inequalities is strict.

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: @Etienne ok so the ratio test is still correct since one of the inequalities in my steps is strict. right?

Comment: In fact, your strict inequality does not hold, because $a_n\to 0$...

Comment: This question has been asked before. However, I cannot find the original question. Somebody please mark it as duplicate, if you can find the original question.

Comment: The duplicate asked to provide a proof, not to check the proposed one. (The simplest proof is to treat separately the cases when $a_n\geqslant1$ infinitely often, and otherwise.)

Comment: I think the Ratio Test is overkill here and you should go with Did's hint.

Comment: I think there is a problem in your proof. We have to prove the existence of this limit $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup |\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}|$ before trying an inequality, only if the limit exists we can apply the ratio test.